# How to show a 2.5D surface of raster above terrain layer in Cesium?

Tags: raster, 3d, elevation, terrain, cesium

I'm developing an web application that will show surfaces of rasters and terrain. These rasters are on GeoTiff format. I learned from example cesium can show image overlays earth surface.

The question is: How to drape a GeoTiff on elevation value provided by its pixel (like the render way of terrain layer) ? Is it possible to add a constant elevation offset to this layer above terrain layer in Cesium ?